# How to get detrennded normal probabylity plot in python?

Tags: python, statistics, normal-distribution, statistica

I need some analogue to "Detrended Normal P-Plot" function from Statistica, but in Python.
[image: Example of the plot]

I only have 1D-array of data, so I need a plot with two axes: X-"Value" and Y-"Deviation from expected value". How can I do it?